# In ASP.NET MVC3 how to get data beloning to related DB tables without create coupling between components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository, viewmodel, service-layer, coupling

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 in C# and Razor. The architecture of the application is divided in Data Access Layer (EF classes + Repository), Service Layer, Controller, ViewModels and View.

I have two EF classes `Products` (key `ProdId`) and `ProductCategories` (key `ProductCategoryId`).

They related through a **one to many relationship** on `ProdCatId` in class `Products`as **foreign key** and `ProductCategoryId` in class `ProductCategories`.

Of course there is also a **navigation property** `hasCategory` from class `Products` to `ProductCategories`.

I have the method in my Repository class:

```
 public IQueryable<Products> GetAllProducts()
 {
      return productDB.Products;
 }
```

Now I want to display in my View all the products with the `ProductCategoryName` (not the `ProdCatId`) of their corresponding category. To access this info in my Repository I use (productDB is the EF class):

```
productDB.Products.Where(n => n.ProdId == prodId)
                  .Select(m => m.hasCategory.ProductCategoryName).First();
```

In order to have this information on my View I should use this code from my **Service Layer**, or worse from my **ViewModel**. This way however, I create coupling between components that I want to keep separated (Service Layer and EF or ViewModel and EF).

If I instead get this value from my Repository (method `string GetProductCategory(int ProdId)`) to my Service Layer, together with the `GetAllProducts().ToList()`, I will have two objects:

1) A `List<Products>`

2) A `string`

How can I pass these values to my Controller to be then wrapped in a ViewModel? Shall I create a class `ProductInfo` in my Service Layer that wraps this data? 
This solution creates coupling between the **Controller**, **ViewModel** and the class **ProductInfo**.

What is the right thing to do not to create coupling?

Answer (score 1):

Two consideration.
1) change the code to

```
repository.GetAllProducts().Products.Where(n => n.ProdId == prodId)
              .Select(m => m.hasCategory.ProductCategoryName).First();
```

This way the code is EF agnostic, and it just use deferred exeution... that means that it will work with everything that supports Linq (Linq2Sql, EF, NHibernate, and so forth)

2) consider solving the problem simply hidrating immediatly the property hasCategory of the Product object. This means not to load them in a lazy way.
This makes sense only if you use an approach that manage the session in the repository or service layer. If you have some kind of session-per-request approach, your property (product.hasCategory.ProductCategoryName) will be populated when needed anyway.

Comment: thanks for the tip. You answer is not what I am looking for. The real problem is to bring these data from the database to the View without creating coupling between different layers. Moreover I do not like to have many in-memory objects, I believe it is possible to achieve what I want using lazy loading and deferred execution at least in the Repository layer

Comment: I don't get your point then. In the code I wrote in point 1, that should be on your service layer, I just use repository layer (the one immediatly under). Than you call that method from your controller (connection between controller and service layer i allowed). And you repository, whi has the GetAllProducts() method, is the only one who knows about EF, because it uses productDB, the EF context. Where is my example breaking the separation of layer?

Comment: I do not liek to have queries in my Service Layer. I'd rather place the code you wrote in my Repository and use a method exposed by my Repository instead of placing it in my Service Layer. Like this there is coupling between the EF and the Service Layer.

Comment: Fair enought. Then you should just expose a method in your service layer that simply call the underline repository method that actually execute the query. This way you are decoupling Controller from Repository through Service, and you won't have any queries in Service. Just a 1:1 mapping method between service and repository will resolve your last issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Product and ProductCategory are the domain models, rather than view models. Google viewmodels and domain models to get a better understand on how they differ.

If I were you I would create a view model called ProductInfoViewModel. This class would contain only the information that you with to display about the product.

```
public class ProductInfoViewModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

You now have a simple class which will be used to display some data.

Yes, you still want to call your repository or service layer in order to get product data:

```
var productDomainModel = productDB.Products.Where(n => n.ProdId == prodId)   
                  .Select(m => m.hasCategory.ProductCategoryName).First();
```

Now, instead of passing productDomainModel to your view, you can create product view model, which will be a lighter as it will contain only the properties that you wish to display:

```
var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel
{
   Name = productDomainModel .Name,
   Category = productDomainModel .Category
}
```

You can now pass this view model to your view:

```
return View(productViewModel);
```

Your view is now aware of a view model, but it doesn't know anything about your domain model, which is a good thing and it promotes a seperation of concerns.

One more thing, when we create a product view model from product domain model, we wrote "boilerplate" code, such as Name = product.Name.

Now image you have 20 properties and you might want to map domain model to view model multiple times. This is a lot of tedious work and you can avoid it by googling tools such as Automapper.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However with your code `var productDomainModel = productDB.Products.Where(n => n.ProdId == prodId).Select(m => m.hasCategory.ProductCategoryName).First();` I just get the a `ProductCategories` projection containing just the `ProductCategory` field.